# JSON syntax error

Tags: syntax-error

```
{
        "manifest_version" : 2,
        "name": "kittenbook", 
        "description" : "Replace photos on Facebook with kittens",
        "version": "0.0.1"
        "content_scripts": [
              {
                    "matches": ["*://www.facebook.com/*"],
                    "js": [kittenbook.js"]
              }
}
```

Can someone explain to me what is wrong with this?

> Failed to load extension from: ~\kittenbook.html Manifest is not valid
>   JSON. Line: 6, column: 3, Syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, the question is completely unclear. What are you taking about? What kind of extension? What language? What markup? What software?

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 errors here.

1. at the end of `"version":"0.0.1"` << missing `,`
2. at the end of `"js":[kittenbook.js"]` << missing `"` and the start of the string
3. also missing `closing []` on the `"content_scripts" :[`

This is the correct JSON syntaxis.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "kittenbook",
    "description": "Replace photos on Facebook with kittens",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "://www.facebook.com/"
            ],
            "js": [
                "kittenbook.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For future testing use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com)